# Extract Images from video and rebuild video with these images

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a very interesting question i think, i did a simple test.

First step: I extract images from a little video (duration: 1 minute and 4 seconds):

```
ffmpeg -i C:\test\video.mp4 -r 30 -s 640x360 -f image2 C:\test\foo-%05d.jpeg
```

Second step: I want to rebuild the initial video with these extracted images with same parameters:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i C:\test\foo-%05d.jpeg -r 30 -s 640x360 C:\test\final.mp4
```

Special result: Initial video (video.mp4) duration was 1 minute and 4 seconds and new video generated (final.mp4) duration is 1 minute and 17 seconds: the new video is longer and the new film seems  slightly slower than the initial video.

My question: Is it possible to get exactly the same film like initial (same duration, same speed) rebuilding the video from its exctrated images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg assumes a default frame rate of 25 when reading individual images as input. See the [`image2` demuxer manual](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-1) for more info.

If you exported your frames at 30 fps, you need to tell ffmpeg to read them with the same framerate:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i C:\test\foo-%05d.jpeg -s 640x360 C:\test\final.mp4
```

Setting an output framerate (`-r 30`) is generally not recommended, and will result in duplicated or dropped frames from the output.

Comment: I would like to add that when transcoding, ffmpeg generates every frame as an image and then reincodes it. That way you save yourself the hassle and I/O needed to generate images on disk.

Comment: @Tarik I'm not sure what you're getting at? Are you assuming the OP is trying to encode a video by generating images, compressing these, and then merging it back together? This doesn't make sense.. combining the images into the final MP4 would mean there's another MPEG-4 encoding step added.

Comment: @slhck that's exactly what he does when getting back the original video from the extracted images: encoding.

Comment: @Tarik Yeah, but what's your point? The OP might be doing something else to the images in between, so re-encoding is necessary.

Comment: @slhck Yep, that's called applying filters.

Comment: old but I don't think you can do it with ffmpeg alone. it being: copy from one stream to another and re-encode on the fly